# Condensing multiple click and submit functions using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I have created a game on a single page, and i have 10 click functions that's triggered on multiple divs that contain forms. Inside the divs are questions that the player has to fill in. I have been able to target each individual form with this line of code: `var answer1 = $('form[name="form1"] >input:text').val()` so that will change for each form `.. [name="form2"]..` and so on. I have asked before in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949886/multiple-jquery-click-functions-on-multiple-forms-on-same-page). So the html is as follows :

```
<div class = "clickbox clickbox1"></div>
<div class = "riddlebox riddlebox1">
//question
<form name="form1">
<input type="text"  value=""/>
</form> 
</div> 

<div class = "clickbox clickbox2"></div>
<div class = "riddlebox riddlebox2">
//question
<form name="form2"> 
<input type="text"  value=""/>
</form> 
</div>
```

and the Jquery to deal with it :

```
$( ".clickbox1" ).click(function() {
  var answered = false;
  $( ".riddlebox1" ).show();
  $('form[name="form1"]').submit(function () {
    var answer1 = $('form[name="form1"] >input:text').val().toLowerCase();
    if (answer1 == //do some checks &&(!answered) ){ 
        answered=true;
        points++;
        $('form[name="form1"] >input:text').val(""); 
    }
return false;
  }); 
});
```

I have 10 of these functions. I'm trying to condense all of this into one function. Would I need to make an instance of `this` each time a div is clicked so I can identify new properties to that instance ? for example answered = false and assigning input text value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "make an instance of `this`". In javascript, `this` is a special variable which references some object, and the object it references depends on how the current function was called.

In jQuery event handlers, the `this` variable refers to the element that triggered the event (in this case, the element that was clicked: `clickbox1`).

If you want to have a single event handler instead of 10 different ones (and this is indeed a good idea!), your event handler should use the `this` variable to determine what to operate on.

So first of all, we want to have a single event handler for all instances of `clickbox`. There are two distinct ways to do that: we can add the handler to all of the `div.clickbox` elements, or we can add a delegated event handler to an element higher up the DOM. Here is what I mean by the second:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickbox', function() {});
```

The second parameter to `on` is a filter which dictates which propagated events should be handled.

Now we want to make your handler function general, in the sense that it uses `this` to find related elements, instead of using hard-coded indexes like `.riddlebox1`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickbox', function() {
   // inside this function, "this" refers to the clicked div
  var answered = false;
  // find the riddlebox which comes after the clicked clickbox
  var $riddlebox = $(this).next(".riddlebox").show();
  $riddlebox.children("form").submit(function () {
    // inside this function, "this" refers to the form
    var $textbox = $(this).find('>input:text');
    var answer1 = $textbox.val().toLowerCase();
    if (answer1 /* do some checks*/ ){ 
        answered=true;
        points++;
        $textbox.val(""); 
    }
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Why did you use children(); instead of find(); ?

Comment: If you know that the element you're looking for is an immediate child of the current element, `children()` only looks in the immediate children, unlike `find()` which looks through all descendants. It can give better performance in general - in this case it wouldn't make any measurable difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach a single handler to all similar elements and then use the `this` reference inside the handler.

Attach a single handler to all elements with the class "clickbox" that opens the next element with the class "riddlebox". Something like this:

```
$('.clickbox').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.riddlebox').show();
});
```

Then attach handlers to the form submit events. I don't think you need to wait until a form is shown to do this. That is, it doesn't have to be inside the click handler above.

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var $form = $this;
    var answer = $form.find('input').val().toLowerCase();
    f (answer == //do some checks && $form.data('answered')){ 
        $form.data('answered', true);
        points++;
        $form.find('input').val('');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Notice how the `.data()` method is used to keep track of whether or not the question for a form has been answered.

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/yZUE9/)